# Countifs array with number of days

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to see how many days people are around between certain blocks.

e.g. with people and the days they are around for listed in the first table (A1:C5) and the blocks in the second table (A6:A10) and the correct answer I'm trying to find a formula for next to it (B6:B10)

```
╔═══╦══════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║   ║    A     ║    B     ║   C  ║
╠═══╬══════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ 1 ║ 15/01/14 ║ 24/04/14 ║ dave ║
║ 2 ║ 24/01/14 ║ 04/02/14 ║  jim ║
║ 3 ║ 25/01/14 ║ 20/02/14 ║ gary ║
║ 4 ║ 10/01/14 ║ 08/02/14 ║  ted ║
║ 5 ║ 19/01/14 ║ 10/02/14 ║  sid ║
╚═══╩══════════╩══════════╩══════╝
╔═══╦══════════╦══════════╗
║   ║    A     ║    B     ║
╠═══╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ 6 ║ 01/01/14 ║   145    ║
║ 7 ║ 01/02/14 ║   106    ║
║ 8 ║ 01/04/14 ║     0    ║
║ 9 ║ 01/06/14 ║     0    ║
╚═══╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

the answer is as it is above because Dave is around 45 days in block 1 (15th Jan-28th Feb) and 55 days in Block 2 (1st Feb-24th March).  Summing that with Jim's 12 days in Block 1, Gary's 35 days in Block 1 and 55 days in Block 2, Ted's 30 days in Block 1 and Sid's 23 days in Block 1 gives the results shown in B6:B9.

I'm looking for a formula I can drag down (I assume an array) that will get me these answers.

Any thoughts anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the block dates overlap from your description, in which case you will need to specify both start and end dates for each block, so with start date of block 1 in `A7` and end date in `B7` use this formula in C7 for the number of days:

`=SUM(IF((A$1:A$5>B7)+(B$1:B$5<A7),0,IF(B$1:B$5>B7,B7,B$1:B$5)-IF(A$1:A$5<A7,A7,A$1:A$5)+1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down

Note that this gives 137 for your sample - Gary has only 27 days, not 35

**Update:**

I found a way to shorten the above using `TEXT` function, i.e.

`=SUM(TEXT(IF(B$1:B$5>B7,B7,B$1:B$5)-IF(A$1:A$5<A7,A7,A$1:A$5)+1,"0;\0")+0)`

Comment: This is exactly it.  My end date for each block is the start of the next block, but I think it'll make it easier me for to make that obvious as you suggest in B6:B9.  Thank you very much for your help

Comment: No problem - I also found a slightly shorter way - should get the same results - I updated my answer

Comment: Again, this works great.  For my own understanding, can you talk me through the `"0;\0"` , please?  I think I understand the `+0` - is this because the final values we've calculated are as text and this makes them back into "summable" numbers again?

Comment: In the first formula the first IF filters out date ranges that don't overlap the block - if you don't use that then negative numbers are returned...but with format `0;\0` positive numbers are returned as integers, negative numbers as zero, so that has the same effect as the IF function. .....and yes, the +0 is then need to convert those text values to real numbers